# Button Event Doesn't Fire In overflow area

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

What I'm trying to do is to move the close button from magnificent popup to outside the lightbox. I'm trying to do this by applying overflow visible to the parent container and positioning it outside. However, in Chrome the following (unwanted) behaviour occurs.

When the close button is clicked inside the lightbox, it closes as is expected. When the button is clicked outside the lightbox (the overflow), the event does not fire.

See the following JS-Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JKhyM/4/

```
// initalize popup
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

jQuery.mp_arv_scoped.open({ 
  items: data,
  type: 'inline',
  inline: {
    markup: '<div class="white-popup"><div class="mfp-close"></div>'+
            '<div class="mfp-content"></div>'+
            '</div>',
  },
   closeMarkup: '<div class="mfp-set-outside"><button class="mfp-close mfp-new-close" type="button" title="Close (Esc)">X</button></div>'
   ,alignTop:false
  ,callbacks: {
    markupParse: function(template, values, item) {
      // optionally apply your own logic - modify "template" element based on data in "values"
      // console.log('Parsing:', template, values, item);
    }
  }
});
```

});

Thank you guys in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just update this css:

Rather than bring your close button out `with top:-15px;` and `right:-15px;`, use:

```
top:0px;
right:0px;
margin-top:-25px;
margin-right:-25px;
```

Use `color:white !important;` to use the color as you want.

Result:

```
.mfp-close {
  overflow: visible;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  margin-top:-25px;
  margin-right:-25px;
  color: white !important;
  font-size: 30px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  font-style: normal;
  background:url('close.png');
  font-family: Arial, Baskerville, monospace;
}
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/JKhyM/6/